# how do I make sure that the user is entering a integer in c?

Tags: c

I want the program to ask the user for a number, and if the user does not enter a number the program will say "input not a integer."

Thx for the help guys!

Comment: You might want to check what e.g. [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns. Or about the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate scanf parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497475/validate-scanf-parameters)

Comment: Read the line of user input with `fgets()`.  If the resultant string successfully parses to an `int`, then it is good, else "input not a integer.".   (Avoid `scanf()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this (it doesn't handle integer overflow):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char buffer[20] = {0};    // 20 is arbitrary;
    int n; char c;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %c", &n, &c) == 1)
            break;

        else
            printf("Input not integer. Retry: ");
    }

    printf("Integer chosen: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Agreed with chux suggestions below!**

Comment: Minor: 1) Could simplify to `"%d %c"`  (first space not needed as %d consumes leading spaces.)  2) Better to `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {;`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way: use `scanf()` function to read the input. It returns the number of items it successfully read.

Another way: read the input as string with `scanf()` of `fgets()` and then try [to parse it as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/633969).